# config-custom.yaml not loading on vagrant / puppet VM

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, puphpet

I'm trying to use a custom config file in my vagrant machine.

I have all the main params in the puphpet\config.yaml
and the local overrides in   puppet\config-custom.yaml

I couldn't get the file to load so after much searching i figured i needed to change the vagrant file

so i added

```
configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")

if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge(custom)
end

data = configValues['vagrantfile-local']
```

but this just gives me

```
Message: NoMethodError: undefined method `deep_merge' for #<Hash:0x00000101b6bac8>
```

originally the code said

```
 configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
```

But that did not work either,

Comment: also tried   configValues.merge(custom) and configValues.merge_yaml(custom)